# Have div match image height with overflow without using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the code shown here:
https://codepen.io/allen-houng/pen/ExYKYdq

and a gist here:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <img class="image" src="imageurl" />
  </div>
  <div class="textWrapper">
   ...lots of text
  </div>
</div>
```

the parent is a flexbox and the two children are flex children. is there anyway to have the textWrapper div match the height of the image while scrolling if content has exceeded height (without using javascript?)

Expected result:
[image]

Actual result:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a fixed height or it should get height from image?

Comment: add `height: 100%` to `.image`.

Comment: The problem with adding height 100% to the image means that the image may not display proportionately.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't do this without javascript. Will all your images be the same height? If so then set the height and width in your css. If not you're going to have to detect the height with javascript and then set textWrapper to that calculated height. Is there a reason you can't use javascript?

Comment: Add a `max-height` property to your parent class and set `overflow-y: scroll;` to your textWrapper class.

Comment: @CharfiOmar maybe you could implement it in the codepen? unable to get it work on my end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First set for the **.parent** `display: flex` to make the column same height,

then set for the **.textWrapper** column `overflow: auto; position: relative`

add a **.inner-text** child element with `position: absolute;`

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
}

.textWrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.textWrapper .inner-text{
    position: absolute;
}
```

here full example:

```css
.parent {
    width: 620px;
    display: flex;
}

.imageWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background:  linear-gradient(red, yellow, green);
    height: 205px;

}

.textWrapper {
    flex: 1;
    background: purple;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.inner-text {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <img class="image" />
    </div>
    <div class="textWrapper">
        <div class="inner-text">
            Fusce consequat. Nulla nisl. Nunc nisl. Duis bibendum, felis sed interdum venenatis, turpis enim blandit mi,
            in porttitor pede justo eu massa. Donec dapibus. Duis at velit eu est congue elementum. Fusce consequat.
            Nulla nisl. Nunc nisl. Duis bibendum, felis sed interdum venenatis, turpis enim blandit mi, in porttitor
            pede justo eu massa. Donec dapibus. Duis at velit eu est congue elementum. Fusce consequat. Nulla nisl. Nunc
            nisl. Duis bibendum, felis sed interdum venenatis, turpis enim blandit mi, in porttitor pede justo eu massa.
            Donec dapibus. Duis at velit eu est congue elementum. Fusce consequat. Nulla nisl. Nunc nisl. Duis bibendum,
            felis sed interdum venenatis, turpis enim blandit mi, in porttitor pede justo eu massa. Donec dapibus. Duis
            at velit eu est congue elementum. Fusce consequat. Nulla nisl. Nunc nisl. Duis bibendum, felis sed interdum
            venenatis, turpis enim blandit mi, in porttitor pede justo eu massa. Donec dapibus. Duis at velit eu est
            congue elementum. Fusce consequat. Nulla nisl. Nunc nisl. Duis bibendum, felis sed interdum venenatis,
            turpis enim blandit mi, in porttitor pede justo eu massa. Donec dapibus. Duis at velit eu est congue
            elementum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use grid, it separates both at the same size, and the parent element will adjust depending of the child sizes. But then one of the child could have `overflow: scroll`, and the other not, so the parent will only adjust to the image.

```
.parent {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

img {
   width: 100%;
}

.text-wrapper {
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

Also, if you have different images sizes, you can crop them all by putting this css style:

```
img {
   object-fit: cover;
   object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

And then put parent style with the desired size:

```
.parent {
   height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Just a note here... this does not work in any version of IE, if that's a concern for you.

Comment: The grid stylings are noavailable in IE.

Answer (score 1):

---

I believe the desired result is not possible with pure CSS. All things are loaded asynchronously on the page and usually images are loaded after text. First of all , when you want to overflow a div , the div needs a fixed height.
Second of all, you want to have a div , that receives height , based on async load of an image from server/url, which is not possible, because you need to handle this event on your own.

One way to work around this with some compromise is to use background-image from the div and fixed height for the text.

```
.parent {
  position:relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  max-height:100vh;
}

.image {
  border:1px solid purple;
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;
}
.textWrapper {
  height:300px;
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color:purple;
  color:white;
}
```

https://codepen.io/kriskys/pen/bGbpGqm

The second way to do it is to set text size when image loads with JavaScript:

```
     $('img').on('load',function(){
       // Create dummy image to get real size
       $("<img>").attr("src", $(img).attr("src")).load(function(){
         var realWidth = this.width;
         var realHeight = this.height;
         $('textWrapper').style({'height':realHeight});
       });
     });
```